# Our GITBLIT/Jetty service has stopped working after new stringent network security at our company

Tags: windows, jetty, gitblit

The GitBlit service on one of our Windows Server 2012 R1 was working just fine until our company implemented hyper-stringent security corporate-wide.

The gitblit service is running, but when trying to reach the gitblit page via web browser results in Jetty error 503, service unavailable.

I've been unable to come up with a google query to find out how I can check to see if jetty is running or how to troubleshoot.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Run a Jetty Server `dump()` from the JMX console on that server (then update this question with the details). (Note: I'm not asking for a thread dump or a heap dump) - See https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-dump-tool.html

Comment: There is no jetty.xml anywhere on the server. I can't even tell if it runs. Doesn't show up in task manager or services.msc

Comment: I'm tracking it down via the gitblit logs. Will post when I see more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that what I needed to do is check the gitblit logs where I found that a colleague across the pond left me with a corrupted config file. When I removed the problem, it started working again.